# Programmatically calculate which bin a value will fall into for a histogram

Tags: histogram, binning

I'm trying to programmatically create a histogram.  The number of bins is specified by the user.  My issue in this problem is that I came up with what I thought was a reasonable way to determine which bin a value goes into.  I first came up with:

$binNum=\lfloor \frac{value \cdot range}{numBins} \rfloor$

Where `value` is a number in the set of data, and `range` is the linear distance between the minimum and maximum values of the data set ($max - min$).  I realized that this wouldn't work when I had negative numbers in my values for two reasons: 1) it gives me negative bins and 2) the floor function doesn't do what I want it to with negative numbers: $\lfloor \frac{-9.84 \cdot (7.94 - (-9.84))}{16} \rfloor = -11$.  I would like the bins to be from 0 to n-1, so I came up with the following when `min` is negative:

$binNum = \lfloor \frac{value \cdot range}{numBins} + \vert \frac{min \cdot range}{numBins} \vert \rfloor$

This was used with the thought that if I add the minimum bin to the first formula, it would shift the bins to the correct  range of $[0, numBins)$.  This, however, has led to too many bins being represented.  For instance, when `min=-9.84, max=7.94, numBins=16`, we get the following for the maximum value's bin: $\lfloor \frac{7.94 \cdot (7.94 - (-9.84)}{16} + \vert\frac{-9.84 \cdot (7.94-(-9.84))}{16}\vert \rfloor = 19$, which is incorrect, it should be 15 (since we're going from 0 - 15).  Any suggestions on how I should calculate my bins?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Thanks for posting an interesting question & showing where you're stuck and what you've tried so far. You don't need to post a disclaimer saying you're new. We can see that from your reputation level anyway and we try not to scare the new posters off!.If anything we'd prefer you don't put a "disclaimer: I'm new" at the start of your post, as it is just a distraction for future readers (and gets in the way in the search results, when readers would rather see the first substantive line of your question in the results). I edited it out but I do appreciate the sentiment!

Comment: (I also don't think the "programming" tag adds much, since the question isn't fundamentally about programming but rather about how to calculate which bin a value falls in. So I've snipped that as well. Feel free to put it back if you think it adds something.)

Comment: Can you specify what __range__, __value__ and __min__ mean here?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work with negative numbers in your values ? If the minimum value is -6 and the maximum is -2 and you need four Bins then the bin length is (-2 - (-6) )/4 ?

Comment: You might be confusing the floor function (as written) with truncation, which is what some programming environments will compute for you. It's difficult to determine what your formulas mean, because you haven't defined what "$value\cdot range$" or "$min\cdots range$" mean, but they seem to be efforts to recreate the correct formula, which for $n$ bins puts a value of any $x$ in the interval $[l, u)$ into bin number $$\lfloor n \frac{x-l}{u-l} \rfloor,$$ where bins are indexed from $0$ through $n-1$. Since both $x-l$ and $u-l$ are non-negative, there is no problem with negative numbers.

Comment: @Silverfish thank you for the useful feedback!  I'm fine with you taking programming out, I just put it in there for clarity's sake.

Comment: @fcop I made some edits concerning the negative values, they now give concrete examples

Comment: @whuber that's the one that I want, put that as the answer and I'll give you credit for it!  Also, to your first point, I was simply going through my thought process and the steps that I tried.  I edited the post to make that more clear.  For the case of my first formula, truncation definitely would've been the effect I was going for had I considered that I would get negative values for bins.

Comment: @whuber actualle, after coding this in, it looks like I get bins 0 - 16 instead of 0 - 15, like I expected.  This means that there are 17 bins instead of 16.

Comment: You will get a bin $16$ when you plug a value of $u$ in for $x$.  The notation "$[l,u)$" in my comment is a standard way of saying $l$ is included but $u$ is *not*.  This is a problem for all algorithms.  (Even the `hist` function in `R` falls into this trap.)  You can resolve it in various ways; one is by replacing $n$ in the formula by a value that is a tiny bit smaller, such as $n(1-10^{-12})$.  Another is by combining bins $n$ and $n+1$ and using a label that indicates the highest bin is all values equal to or greater than its left endpoint.

Comment: @whuber thank you.  I'll just combine by your suggestion.